# WordPress plugin and wp_head

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've re-edited this question: is possible to before to show the output in point 2 pass  a variable to global color (point 3) like a global variable or something?

```
        class myclass
        {
             public function init()
             {
                  global $shortcode_tags;
                      add_shortcode( MYSHORTCODE, array( 'myclass', 'shortcode' ) );
                  // * point 1
                  return;

             }

             public function shortcode( )
             {
                 // *point2
             } 

             function globalcolor($color)


              {
                     echo '<style>body{color:' .$color . '}</style>' . "\n";
                     // * point 3
                 }
            }

add_action( 'wphead', array( 'myclass', 'globalcolor' ) ); 

add_action( 'init', array( 'myclass', 'init' ) );
```

PS. right now im reading about custom fields.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_action()` is called by WordPress, you want [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

The action `init` comes way too early. You call the class now even for the backend, for AJAX requests etc. Use the hook `template_redirect` which is called on the frontend only.

You cannot send the color value the way you tried. See the sample code for a working example.

Sample code:

```
class My_Plugin {

    /**
     * Container for your color value.
     * @var string
     */
    static $color;

    public static function init()
    {
        // Set the color value as a class member.
        self::$color = '#345';

        // Class methods are addressed with an array of the object or the
        // class name and the function name.
        add_action( 'wp_head', array ( __CLASS__, 'print_color' ) );
    }

    public static function print_color() 
    {
        // In action you have to print/echo to get an output.
        print '<style>body{color:' . self::$color . '}</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', array ( 'My_Plugin', 'init' ) );
```

I strongly recommend https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ to ask more questions on WordPress. :)

Comment: thanks, but im not clear at all, also I've updated with my full scheme.

Comment: @greenbandit That’s a … complete new question. ;) Shortcodes are parsed **after** `wp_head`. Use a [custom field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-field) instead.

Comment: @toscho good point about shortcode, main idea is add a custom color and background via shortcode like [background color="#0066ff" bg="url"] any ideas?

Comment: @greenbandit It is plain impossible without output buffering. And you don’t want to go that way, really. Use custom fields. Shortcodes aren’t made for what you want.

Comment: @toscho thanks again, can you point me in the right direction to use custom fields? and thanks again for taking your time.

Comment: @greenbandit The first page of [these results](http://is.gd/05dlOk) (from my custom WordPress search engine) offers quite useful resources.

Comment: @toscho amazing dude, is more easy as I expected, i've re-edited the question because i need to understand why. thanks again. btw are you free to help me with this? obviously not for free.

Comment: @greenbandit Sorry, no. I don’t take such small jobs anymore.